# unable to update the table using session variable

Tags: php, mysql, session, variables

i wanted to update the information of the particular user, using the session variable but when i use the session variable in the where clause, the row is not affected.

here i am storing the value of the session variable 'username' into the variable $user, and i am using the $user variable in the update where clause to update the row. But when i update it not getting updated.
here is the code i used:

```
<?php
//session_start();
 include '../global_config/databaseconfig.php';
global $user;
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];}
echo $user;
 global $fname;global $lname;global $phno;global $gender;
if(isset($_POST['fname'])){ $fname = $_POST['fname']; }
if(isset($_POST['lname'])){ $lname = $_POST['lname']; }
if(isset($_POST['phno'])){ $phno = $_POST['phno']; }
if(isset($_POST['gender'])){ $gender = $_POST['gender']; }
echo $fname;
// $lname = $_POST['lname'];
//$user variable contains the username

  $tbl_name = "members";
  // $host = "localhost"; // Host name
  // $username = "root"; // Mysql username
  // $password = ""; // Mysql password
  // $db_name = "login"; // Database name
  // $tbl_name = "members"; // Table name
  //CONNECTION
  $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$db_name);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

// echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1",$username,$password,$db_name, 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
// echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
$result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `members` SET `firstname`='$fname' WHERE `username`='$user'");
printf("Affected rows (SELECT): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);


 ?>
```

Comment: why are you not starting your session?

Comment: The SQL `UPDATE ...` statement does not use the `$user` variable, it just says `WHERE username='test'`

Comment: On a side note, it's dangerous to use `$_POST` data directly in a SQL statement, you're opening a big security hole known as an SQL Injection Attack. This webpage explains more and how to prevent it: http://packetcode.com/article/preventing-sql-injection-php-security

Comment: i am able to print the value of the session variable, but  not able to update using it in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help.

```
   //use this at the beginning  of the file
    @session_start();
```

Need to start the sessions before using it.